# How is the health of your individual cubs represented in Shelter?

Tags: shelter

Is there a visual indicator for the health of your cubs in [Shelter](http://shelterthegame.com/)?

I know the aesthetics of the game require a HUD-less experience, and as such there aren't any health meters present. Since the purpose of the game is to continually forage for food for your cubs, and protect them from danger, I figured there had to be some way of knowing which of them has the least amount of what-ever counts as hit points in the game.

Answer (score 5):

There is a visual representation of the *health* of the individual cubs in [Shelter](http://www.shelterthegame.com/), and it's done through the [tint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tint) of the cub's color. A "well fed" cub has a colored coat that is almost the same as the mother badger. As time goes on, the color of the cub's coat will start to lighten towards the color of the dying cub from the beginning cave-sequence of the game if the cub has not been fed recently.